# VPN over PPTP on mac os sierra

Tags: vpn, pptp, macos-sierra

Lately I discovered that connecting to a VPN via PPTP option has been removed in the new mac os - sierra.
I tried multiple application to do so - all failed.
How can I connect to my VPN over PPTP?

ps. I don't want to use L2TP because I don't have a pre shared key (I also don't know what it is).

Comment: I voted to closed this question as it rather belongs to AskDifferent, anyway, there is a question with answers. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250522/connection-l2tp-via-ipsec-to-vpn-as-pptp-vpn-no-longer-supported-on-macos-sierra

Comment: Here is tutorial how to do it with terminal https://filipmolcik.com/pptp-vpn-on-macos-sierra-and-high-sierra/

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498181/how-to-programmatically-create-a-pptp-vpn-connection-on-macos-sierra-high-sierra

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The FlowVPN client is free (and works with any provider).

It supports PPTP and OpenVPN on macOS Sierra:

https://www.flowvpn.com/download-mac/

Just overwrite the FlowVPN server address with any server and it connects.

Comment: How to overwrite the FlowVPN server address? It is a drop-down menu.

Comment: Basic costs, it's not free.

Comment: @sparkandshine You can type inside the dropdown menu if you place your cursor in it.

Comment: I cant get it to connect to our windows server. It keeps giving me `EAP refuse to authenticate using type 26`. Shimo works fine, but is 30 day trail version.

Comment: FlowVPN is not free.

Comment: @Robula "FlowVPN's services are not free. FlowVPN's client software is free to download and use with non-FlowVPN services."

Comment: version I tried today does not seem to allow custom IP, only list of servers and dropdown cannot be changed. -1

Comment: They do not allow custom IP settings in new version, please update the answer.

Comment: FlowVPN client worked for me. Connecting from MacOS X 10.13.5 to Asus RT-N66R PPTP VPN. Please note that PPTP is much less secure than IPSec with pre-shared key.

Comment: YES! YES! THANK YOU!

Comment: not working on big sur 11.2.1

Answer (score 1):

VPN PPTP in Sierra is dismissed because it is not a secure method of communication.
To solve the problem; you can install software [Shimo](https://www.shimovpn.com) that works with the operating system Sierra

Comment: Any free clients?

Comment: https://www.flowvpn.com/download-mac

Comment: With Shimo I have problems, buggy. Have to restart it all the time. I use https://www.flowvpn.com it's free.

Comment: flow isn't free, its 4 bucks a month...

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell just to use the client? Or is it $4 a month for a subscription to use their VPN servers?

Comment: Shimo isn't free.   They want 49EU to purchase.  As far as I can tell that is a one time fee and they have a 30-day free trial.

Comment: FlowVPN sucks you can create simple client with Automator.app here is how: https://filipmolcik.com/pptp-vpn-on-macos-sierra-and-high-sierra/