# How to programmatically create a PPTP VPN connection on macOS Sierra/High Sierra?

Tags: macos, perl, macos-sierra, ppp, pptp

Apple removed high-level PPTP support in macOS Sierra from its network configuration system. However, the PPP internals are all still there, including `/usr/sbin/pppd` and `/etc/ppp/`.

How can I programmatically initiate a PPTP VPN connection on macOS Sierra / High Sierra using what's left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer:

This method creates a PPTP connection that **doesn't** send all traffic and **doesn't** override other DNS providers, meaning it works with multiple simultaneous VPN connections each having different DNS search domains, and closes it in an orderly fashion.

Not sending all traffic requires you to know the VPN subnet beforehand. If you don't, you must send all traffic (see below), since vanilla PPP/LCP has no means to tell the client its subnet (although theoretically the `ip-up` and `ip-down` scripts could guess it from the received IP address).

Save this perl as `/usr/local/bin/pptp`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
if (@ARGV) {
    my $name = $ARGV[0];
    if (length $name && -e "/etc/ppp/peers/$name") {
        my $pid;
        $SIG{"INT"} = "IGNORE";
        die "fork: $!" unless defined ($pid = fork);
        if ($pid) { # parent
            $SIG{"INT"} = sub {
                kill HUP => $pid;
            };
            wait;
            exit;
        } else { #child
            $SIG{"INT"} = "DEFAULT";
            exec "pppd", "call", $name;
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        print "Error: PPTP name: $name\n";
    }
} else {
    opendir my $d, "/etc/ppp/peers" or die "Cannot read /etc/ppp/peers";
    while (readdir $d) {
        print "$_\n" if !($_ eq "." || $_ eq "..");
    }
    closedir $d;
}
```

Run it as `sudo pptp AcmeOffice`, where `AcmeOffice` is the PPP connection name, and close it with a single Control-C/SIGINT.

In `/etc/ppp/peers`, create the PPP connection file, in this example `/etc/ppp/peers/AcmeOffice`:

```
plugin /System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp
plugin PPTP.ppp
noauth
# debug 
redialcount 1
redialtimer 5
idle 1800
#mru 1320
mtu 1320
receive-all
novj 0:0
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
#refuse-chap-md5
refuse-eap
hide-password
#noaskpassword
#mppe-stateless 
mppe-128 
mppe-stateful 
require-mppe 
passive 
looplocal 
nodetach
# defaultroute
#replacedefaultroute
# ms-dns 8.8.8.8
# usepeerdns
noipdefault
# logfile /tmp/ppp.AcmeOffice.log 
ipparam AcmeOffice
remoteaddress office.acme.com
user misteracme
password acme1234
```

The last 4 options are connection-specific. Note the password is stored cleartext. `chown root:wheel` and `chmod 600` is recommended. `nodetach`, `ipcp-accept-local`, `ipcp-accept-remote`, `noipdefault` are critical.

Since we're not becoming/replacing the default route, you must manually change your routing table. Add an `AcmeOffice` entry to the `/etc/ppp/ip-up` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#params: interface-name tty-device speed local-IP-address remote-IP-address ipparam

PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin

case "$6" in
    AcmeOffice)
        route -n add -net 192.168.1.0/24 -interface "$1"
        ;;
    AcmeLab)
        route -n add -net 192.168.2.0/24 -interface "$1"
        ;;
    AcmeOffshore)
        route -n add -net 192.168.3.0/24 -interface "$1"
        ;;
    VPNBook)
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```

and your `/etc/ppp/ip-down` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#params: interface-name tty-device speed local-IP-address remote-IP-address ipparam

PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin

case "$6" in
    AcmeOffice)
        route -n delete -net 192.168.1.0/24 -interface "$1"
        ;;
    AcmeLab)
        route -n delete -net 192.168.2.0/24 -interface "$1"
        ;;
    AcmeOffshore)
        route -n delete -net 192.168.3.0/24 -interface "$1"
        ;;
    VPNBook)
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```

If the VPN has a DNS search domain (i.e. `somehost.office.acme.com`), create a file in `/etc/resolver/` named after the DNS suffix, like `/etc/resolver/office.acme.com`, with contents like:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
domain office.acme.com
```

Note that this requires knowing the destination domain & nameserver beforehand. Theoretically `ip-up` & `ip-down` could create & delete this file on demand.

To send all traffic (& if you don't know the destination subnet), uncomment `#defaultroute` in the PPP connection file and leave the `ip-up` & `ip-down` entries blank (e.g. the `VPNBook` example). To override your DNS with the VPN's, uncomment `usepeerdns`.